# How to retain the double-column formatting of the previous page after \clearpage?

Tags: page-breaking, vertical-alignment, two-column, revtex

I'd like to have some additional material after a paper, starting on a new page. For this purpose I'm using `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` (`\newpage` doesn't work the way I want). Unfortunately, while the new material indeed starts on a new page, the previous page (the last page of the paper) loses the proper double-column formatting. That last page only displays one column for a shorter text or two columns unequal in length. How can the proper double-column formatting be retained for that page also?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,twoside]{revtex4}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Main Text}
\lipsum[1-7]
\clearpage
\section*{Additional Material}
\lipsum[8-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This definetely needs a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I think OP is looking for an explanation why two-column work isn't balanced by default, and a way to achieve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,twoside]{revtex4}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\balancecolsandclearpage}{%
  \close@column@grid
  \clearpage
  \twocolumngrid
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Main Text}
\lipsum[1-7]
\balancecolsandclearpage
\section*{Additional Material}
\lipsum[8-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot @lockstep. Hope I've properly given you the due credits this time.